# Show that if $K\subset\ell^{1}$ is compact, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{j}|<\epsilon$ uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification

This question is related to the online note I referred in this post: [Describe all the compact subsets of $\ell^{1}$ -- General Result Proved, Example Needed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870113/describe-all-the-compact-subsets-of-ell1-general-result-proved-example)

The online note there missed a proof of one direction, which can be described as

> If $K\subset \ell^{1}$ is compact, then we must have $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{\mathbf{x}\in K}\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{j}|=0.$$

This is saying that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ (only depends on $\epsilon$) such that $$\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{j}| < \epsilon$$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in K$.

I tried to prove this but it turned out in the end that my $N$ depends on the choice of $\mathbf{x}$. My proof is as follows:

As it is compact, it is totally bounded and closed. Let $\mathbf{x}\in K$ and $\epsilon>0$, then by total boundedness, there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbf{x}_{1},\cdots, \mathbf{x}_{m}\in X$ and $\gamma\in \{1,\cdots,m\}$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}-x_{\gamma, i}|<\epsilon.$$

Note that since $\mathbf{x}_{\gamma}\in X$, $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_{\gamma, j}|<\infty$, which implies that there exists $N$ large enough such that $\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{\gamma, j}|<\epsilon.$

Hence, we have $$\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{j}|=\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{j}-x_{\gamma, j}+x_{\gamma, j}|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_{j}-x_{\gamma, j}|+\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{\gamma, j}|<\epsilon+\epsilon=2\epsilon.$$

---

The problem in my proof is that $N$ depends on the choice of $\mathbf{x}_{\gamma}$, and the choice of $\mathbf{x}_{\gamma}$ depends on the choice of my $\mathbf{x}$.

What should I do to fix this? or my proof is actually correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of totally boundedness is different to what you used in your argument.

$K$ being totally bounded implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $\mathbf x_1, \dots, \mathbf x_m \in K$ such that **for all** $\mathbf x \in K$, **there exists** a $\gamma \in \{1, \dots, m \}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}-x_{\gamma, i}|<\epsilon.$

The rest of your argument then works!

Concretely, fix an $\epsilon > 0$ and pick $\mathbf x_1, \dots, \mathbf x_m \in K$ such that for all $\mathbf x \in K$, there exists a $\gamma \in \{1, \dots, m \}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}-x_{\gamma, i}|<\epsilon$, and pick an $N$ large enough such that $\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{\gamma, j}|<\epsilon$ for all of these $\gamma$'s.

For **any** given $\mathbf x \in K$, let $\gamma$ be the **particular** $\gamma$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}-x_{\gamma, i}|<\epsilon.$ Then

$$\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{j}|=\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{j}-x_{\gamma, j}+x_{\gamma, j}|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_{j}-x_{\gamma, j}|+\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{\gamma, j}|<\epsilon+\epsilon=2\epsilon.$$

Thus the $N$ depends on the choice of $\epsilon$ (which it is allowed to), but the $N$ does not depend on the choice of $\mathbf x$.

Comment: Nice. so in the totally boundedness, the choice of $\mathbf{x}_{1},\cdots,\mathbf{x}_{m}$ works for all $\mathbf{x}$. Nice!

Comment: oh by the way, you mean $\mathbf{x}_{1},\cdots,\mathbf{x}_{m}\in X$, right? not in $K$

Comment: Could be either $X$ or $K$ here

Comment: nice. thanks for the nice answer.